# Does pushforward map preserve integral curves?

Tags: differential-geometry, symmetry

Let $X$ be a vector field on the manifold $M$ and let $Y$ be a vector field on $N$. Denote with $e^{tX}$, $e^{tY}$ the *flows* they generate, that is 
$$
u(t)=e^{tX}p\quad \text{is the unique solution to }\quad \begin{cases} \dot{u}(t)=X_{u(t)} \\ u(0)=p\end{cases}$$ 
and similarly for $e^{tY}$. Assume that both $X$ and $Y$ are *complete*, meaning that $e^{tX}$ and $e^{tY}$ are defined for all $t\in \mathbb{R}$, regardless of the initial condition.

> Let $F\colon M \to N$ be smooth. By differentiating at $t=0$, one sees that the property $$\tag{1} F(e^{tX}p)=e^{tY}F(p),\quad \forall p\in M,\ \forall t \in \mathbb{R}$$ implies $$\tag{2} F_{\star{}p}X_p=Y_{F(p)}, \quad \forall p \in M,$$ the term $F_\star$ denoting the [push-forward](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pushforward_%28differential%29#Pushforward_of_vector_fields).
>
> **Question**. Does $(2)$ imply $(1)$?

In the special case $M=\mathbb{R}^n, N=\mathbb{R}$ and 
$$
e^{tX}p=e^t p,\quad e^{tY}\lambda=e^{k t}\lambda, $$
the equivalence between (1) and (2) holds, and it is called [Euler's homogeneous function theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homogeneous_function#Positive_homogeneity).

Comment: [Related](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/705742/8157).

Comment: By the way, I think a better title would be something like "does pushforward map preserve integral curves?". This will help future readers find this question while searching. (It is true that this is also a generalization of Euler's homogeneous function theorem, but I think that the more natural context is differential geometry).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is positive. By differentiating, and using the assumption $F_{\star{}}X=Y \circ F$ you can see that both

$ t \to F(e^{tX}p), \, \, t \to  e^{tY}F(p) $ are integral curves of $Y$ starting at the point $F(p)$. By the uniqueness of such creatures, you are done.

By the way, this is essentially Proposition 9.6 in Lee's book on smooth manifolds.

Comment: Thank you! Are you sure about the reference? On my copy of that book (John Lee), 9.6 is a lemma about the wedge product.

Comment: Yes, I checked again. I am using the *second* edition. The title of the proposition is called "Naturality of integral curves".

Comment: I checked [on google books](https://books.google.es/books?id=eqfgZtjQceYC&lpg=PA615&vq=naturality%20of%20integral%20curves&pg=PA213#v=onepage&q&f=false) and I found yet another thing! :-D Crazy. Anyway, it is not important. Thank you for your time!

Comment: I think the version in Google Books is the first edition of the book, not the second one.

Comment: @GiuseppeNegro: The result that Asaf is referring to is indeed Proposition 9.6 in the second edition of my book. In the first edition, there's an Example 9.6, showing that a Lie group homomorphism is equivariant. The version of the book in which Lemma 9.6 is about wedge products is an illegally pirated early draft of the first edition, which somebody posted on the internet without my permission. It's full of errors, and I don't recommend trying to study from it.

Comment: @JackLee: Thank you very much for this warning. I was completely unaware of this fact.