# Does orthogonal-invariance of a differential imply invariance of the function?

Tags: lie-groups, symmetry, orthogonal-matrices, symmetric-functions

Let $U:\text{Hom}(\mathbb{R}^d,\mathbb{R}^d) \to \mathbb{R}$ be a smooth function .

If $U$ is orthogonally-invariant, i.e. $U(QA)=U(A)$ for every $Q \in \text{SO}(n),A \in \text{Hom}(\mathbb{R}^d,\mathbb{R}^d)$, then

$$ dU_{QA}(QB)=dU_{A}(B) \tag{1}$$

Does the converse hold? That is, suppose $U$ is a $C^{\infty}$ function whose differential satisfies equation $(1) $ for every $A,B\in \text{Hom}(\mathbb{R}^d,\mathbb{R}^d),Q\in \text{SO}(n)$. Is it true that $U(QA)=U(A)$ for every $Q \in \text{SO}(n)$?

Comment: You don't really need $f$ periodic: it's sufficient for $f$ to be bounded, which follows from the domain of $h$ being compact

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is positive. Indeed, define $h:\text{SO}(n) \to \mathbb{R}$, by
$$ h(Q)=U(QA).$$

Then, $dh_Q(\tilde B)=dU_{QA}(\tilde BA)=dU_{A}(Q^{-1}\tilde BA)=dh_I(Q^{-1}\tilde B)$, 
so 
$$ dh_Q = dh_I \circ Q^{-1}   \,\,\,\text{  for every } Q \in \text{SO}(n). \tag{1}$$

Since $\text{SO}(n)$ is compact, $h$ obtains a maximum at some point $P \in \text{SO}(n)$. Thus, $dh_P=0$, hence by equation $(1)$, $dh_I=0$, and so $dh_Q =0$ for every $Q \in \text{SO}(n)$. This implies $h$ is constant.

*Comment:* This argument use the compactness of the symmetry group $\text{SO}(n)$ in an essential way; indeed, for non-compact groups $G$, "differential invariance" of a function $G \to \mathbb{R}$ does not imply it is constant. Take e.g. $G=\mathbb{R}$, and $f(x)=x$.

Comment: Nice! [This old question of mine](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1726103/8157) is somewhat reminiscent of the present one. Maybe your last comment answers it, in the negative.

Comment: Your question is nice indeed, however the answer turns out to be positive.